# JasperReports: How to add font not in the application classpath

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, classloader

I am trying to use a font, that is not installed on my local OS, with a `JasperReports`. The jasper report uses in this way:

```xml
<textField>  
  <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="137" height="20"/>  
        <textElement>  
    <font fontName="Corbel" size="12"/>  
    </textElement>  
    <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{something}]]></textFieldExpression>  
</textField>
```

The font named *`Corbel`* was exported as a font extension (using iReport) and is contained in file (Corbel.jar), in folder, on my system.
I add this extension to the classpath of the application, using a code as follows:

```java
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {new URL("file:///D:/path/to/Corbel_jar_folder/")});  
param = new HashMap();    
param.put(JRParameter.REPORT_CLASS_LOADER, cl);  
jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("d:/path/to/Report_with_Corbel_font.jrxml");  
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

After the report is filled, I export it using a `JRPdfExporter`. However, in the result pdf file, the element does not have the *`Corbel`* font applied. I have not included the pdf exporting, because I think that the problem is somewhere with the filling.
I have searched and read numerous posts and questions related to using/including fonts (i.e.font extensions) in `JasperReports`; still I am not aware of where the mistake or the problem resides.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance! (sorry for the bad code indentation and I hope I have included enough details)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that the loading of font extensions jars is done from the thread context classloader and from the `JRParameter.REPORT_CLASS_LOADER`, nor the `JRExporterParameter.CLASS_LOADER`.

Therefore, in my case, the current (initial) thread classloader had to be saved, the we had to do something like `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl)`, where `cl` was the context of the `JasperReports` based application and then the thread context classloader was reverted to the original one.

The question has been answered and details are available [here](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=76180).

I hope this answer will help others facing similar (font) issues.

Answer (score 3):

**Jasper Reports: Adding Custom Fonts**

1. Get the font files you want to use ( TTF, EOT, SVG or WOFF (OTF converted to TTF 
   works as well))
2. Add the fonts to Jaspersoft Studio (or iReport) using the UI. (Window->Preferences->Jaspersoft Studio->Fonts)

   [image: Add Font]

   You need to give details as in the image. Specially PDF Font Name field is misleading. We need to give the path here for this font in font-extention.jar which we create in next step.

   Now you can preview the font in your report.

   [image: Font Added]
3. Export the fonts to a fonts-extention.jar file for use in your application. Select and Export required fonts. (Window->Preferences->Jaspersoft Studio->Fonts->Select and Export)
4. Take care of integrating the jar into your build. If you are using maven for your project you can integrate as follows.

```xml
        <dependency>
           <groupId>local.jasperFont</groupId>
           <artifactId>local.jasperFont</artifactId>
           <version>1.0</version>
           <scope>system</scope>
           <systemPath>${basedir}/src/main/resources/reports/fonts-extension.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

And add the fonts-extension.jar in project resources/reports directory.

Answer (score 0):

We could use Google Noto fonts with Jasper with these steps

1. Packaging the NotoSans family into a jar file as instructed in
   Jasper documentation.
2. Uploaded this jar to our maven repo
3. Define dependency in pom

> ```
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>com.crunchtime.shared.fonts</groupId>
>   <artifactId>notosans</artifactId>
>   <version>1.0</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

4. And then use in our. I think this is the hardest part but this is how we did it

private static final String DEFAULT_PDF_STYLE = "defaultPdf";

private static final String DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY = "NotoSans";

private static final String CJK_FONT = "fonts/NotoSansCJKtc-Regular.otf";

```
   if (language-other-than-English) {
        defaultStyle.setPdfFontName(CJK_FONT);
    } else {
        defaultStyle.setFontName(DEFAULT_FONT_FAMILY);
    }
```

We had been seeing this null pointer exception but the key was to set explicitly set the font for the pdf