# How do I display Japanese fonts in PDF via Jasper Reports (without embedding fonts)?

Tags: pdf, unicode, fonts, jasper-reports

I am creating a report with Japanese characters and the characters show in iReport correctly but when using the PDF exporter the Japanese characters are invisible.

I simply want to use the MS Mincho font in the PDF report or the standard PDF Japanese font but have no idea how to configure. I know there is a similar question on Stack overflow but the answers to that question are inconclusive and do not work.

I am using iText 3.7.3 and Jasper Reports 3.7.3 with iText 2.1.7 as the PDF exporting library. Earlier versions of Jasper used to use the iTextAsian.jar for exporting Japanese fonts but that no longer seems the case. Is there anyone with any know-how how to get Japanese PDFs working with the new version?

Thanks,

Comment: You should use [font-extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/jasper-reports/5773/font-extensions)

Comment: You can refer this. [Jasper Reports: Adding Custom Fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151562/jasperreports-how-to-add-font-not-in-the-application-classpath/51639613#51639613)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the embeded font of PDF reader, make sure to specify correct `PDF Font name` and `PDF Encoding` in report element(refer the answer of [Japanese fonts not visible in the export pdf in iReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7049926/japanese-fonts-not-visible-in-the-export-pdf-in-ireports)
)

In this case, `MS Mincho` font is only used to caculated the actual hight/weight when report rendering.

You can copy iTextAsian.jar from older version, remember to add it to classpath.