# Japanese fonts not visible in the export pdf in iReports

Tags: unicode, fonts, jasper-reports, ireport, export-to-pdf

I ran a report through iReport which consists of data in Japanese. When I preview it, through internal Preview, I am able to the see the data in Japanese. But when i do a PDF Preview, none of the Japanese characters are visible.

I use iReport 4.1.1. I installed Adobe Reader 9.

Can anyone suggest me how can I get the japanese fonts in PDF.

Waiting for the reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you set "iTextAsian.jar" to classpath ?

And configure font and encode.

Japanese font : "HeiseiKakuGo-W5" or "HeiseiMin-W3"

Japanese encode : "UniJIS-UCS2-H", "UniJIS-UCS2-V", "UniJIS-UCS2-HW-H" or "UniJIS-UCS2-HW-V"