# JasperReport load font extension

Tags: jasper-reports

I do not use JasperServer, instead I created a webapp using JasperReport 4.0.2 directly.

Templates are not in the default classloader, there are added, using a `ContextClassLoader` before calling JasperReport.

In recent version of Jasper Report font management changed as indicated in [this document](http://www.jaspersoft.com/sites/default/files/jw-presentations/JW11_JasperReports_Tips_And_Tricks_TeodorDanciu%2002.pdf). Therefore I need to provide the Font JARs, which works when I put them in the **WEB-INF/lib** directory directly.

However, for modularity reasons I would like to add them to the classpath using the same `ContextClassloader` as done with the templates, but in that case, texts are not rendered with the correct font.

I do think this has something to do with the way JasperReport loads the Font.
Using a debugger I could track it back to the `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.getFontInfo(...)` method that does not return the same result.

This is due to the fact that `ExtensionsEnvironment.getExtensionsRegistry().getExtensions(FontFamily.class)` does not returns the same family list in both cases. Extensions are only loaded when JARs are place in **WEB-INF/lib**.

Does someone knows how the `net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.getExtensionsRegistry()` could be adapted to retrieve threadRegistry instance instead? (must be initialized somehow I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue seems to be a duplicate of  http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=102&forumid=103&topicid=76180

When JasperReport load the extension (lazily, on first use) the font extension is uses JasperReport Classloader, not the context class loader.

```
 From JRLoader.getClassLoaderResources(String) line:
            Map<URL, ClassLoaderResource> resources =
                  new LinkedHashMap<URL, ClassLoaderResource>();
            collectResources(resource, JRLoader.class.getClassLoader(), resources);
```

`JRLoader.collectResources` then get a list of all classloader by iterating on `.getParent()`.

Using `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` instead an handling errors should provide the extended classloader (which need to have `JRLoader.class.getClassLoader()` set as parent).

Changing the classloader used in JasperReport code fixes the issue but could however have side effects on other use cases.

Comment: I also had another issue because the ContextClassLoader was set back to early when generating the document. I moved it in the finally block. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3151562/jasperreports-how-to-add-font-not-in-the-application-classpath for related discution